# Excel 2016 zipped folder - what is the content of XL>Drawings folder

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, xlsx

i see a lot of Excel files that have problems with performance on good machines... the files are small - 1-5 MB.
When i unzip them there is always the folder "Drawings" in XL folder (unzipped they can get to 100MB)- when i gets deleted the files work flawlessly.
Why it gets created? What users are doing wrong when creating/copying Excel files?

Whats the content of that folder? Seems nothing get deleted from the excel content when this folder is gone...

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://professor-excel.com/xml-zip-excel-file-structure/) discusses the file layout in detail. In my test, adding an image and deleting the drawing folder forced excel to recover the file without the image. It could be in certain cases the drawing info can be recovered, but if it were my data, I wouldn't trust that capability. YMMV

Comment: Hmm, but there are no drawings in the file... never seen them.  Why there would be a drawing folder then?

Comment: I can't say. You can delete the data if you feel it is unnecessary, but it is risky in IMO.